# put images in split by pages

Tags: html, image, pagination

I have 100 images to put on my website in one div. I want to put 20 images and give page numbers in the down, so that if user clicks on '2' it takes to next 20 images. How is this possible. I have tried searching, but could not find any answer

Comment: It's called pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Depends really how your page serves these images. If you have a static HTML page then your only option would be to use JavaScript/jQuery.

If info about your images is serves from a database behind your web application then you can use pagination and routing. For instance you could have an url `http://mydomain.com/images` and this would select the first 20 images from your database then bellow you gallery you can have a set of links Previous and Next and when you click on Next it takes you to the url `http://mydomain.com/images/20` still the gallery page only /20 appended to it to use as an offset for your SQL Query.

Tho seems what you really need is just a simply jQuery image gallery something like this:

1. http://www.tn3gallery.com/?refCode=fe8775
2. http://galleria.io/
3. http://spaceforaname.com/galleryview/#
4. http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/24/multimedia-gallery/